# Is there a way to stop the MobileMe synchronization from Terminal?

Tags: snow-leopard, data-synchronization, mobileme

It happens to me that, sometimes, the MobileMe synchronization starts when it should not, when Mac OS X is busy doing something time-consuming. In such cases, I try to stop the synchronization using its menu extra, but for some reasons the synchronization doesn't stop.
Is there a way to stop it from Terminal?

Comment: I find it best to disconnect from the network (which is doable by taking down the active interfaces or modifying the routing tables) and then letting the sync time out. You can then disable it. This might be of use to people that don't want to killall in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
sudo kill -9 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DotMacSyncManager.framework/Versions/A/Resources/mobilemesyncclient
```

I don't use Mobile Me so cannot test this but this is the location of the Mobile Me sync command.  So killing it should stop the syncing.

Comment: The command returns the error "Illegal process ID."

Comment: yes, it will when the Sync command is not running.  Did you try running the command whilst it was syncing?

Comment: I tried it when the synchronization was running, but in two different Macs I got the following error message: "-bash: kill: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DotMacSyncManager.framework/Versions/A/Resources/mobilemesyncclient: arguments must be process or job IDs".

Comment: I tried "killall −9 mobilemesyncclient," and it worked.

Comment: ah cool.  Glad you figured it out ;)